# is rollback possible in hibernate if one transaction fails among multiple transaction to different tables?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one method :

```
    // methods
    private void transform(TransformList transformList) {
    TableA tA = transformList.getTableA();
    TableB tB = transformList.getTableB();
    TableC tC = transformList.getTableC();

    daoObj.saveA(tA);
    daoObj.saveB(tB);
    daoObj.saveC(tC);
    }
```

Now,

```
    //saveA mehtod
    public void saveA(TableA tA)  {
    Session session = Context.getHibernateSession();
    try {
    if(session != null) {
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    session.merge(tA);
    tx.commit();
    }

    }catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
    throw new SomeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
    if (session != null) {
    session.clear();
    }
    }
    }
```

Similarly,

```
    //saveB mehtod
    public void saveB(TableB tB)  {
    Session session = Context.getHibernateSession();
    try {
    if(session != null) {
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    session.merge(tB);
    tx.commit();
    }       
    }catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
    throw new SomeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
    if (session != null) {
    session.clear();
    }
    }
    }
```

And,

```
        //saveC mehtod
        public void saveC(TableC tC)  {
        Session session = Context.getHibernateSession();
        try {
        if(session != null) {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        session.merge(tC);
        tx.commit();
        }       
        }catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw new SomeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
        if (session != null) {
        session.clear();
        }
        }
        }
```

Now while calling 'transform' method, if saveA and saveB method are success and then some
exception occurs in saveC method, is it possible to rollback TableA and TableB records
(which are committed already) along with TableC records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll have move your transaction handling at least one level higher: create a transaction, and call saveA(), saveB() and saveC() inside that transaction. Don't handle transactions inside the save methods.

Of course, this is only one possibility. There are frameworks, like Spring, that greatly help you manage your transactions.

Comment: Than should i  pass the common Session object as well to all the 3 methods?

Comment: If you need it (and from the code it look like it), yes you'll have to pass the session as a parameter, or keep it somewhere the methods can look it up.

Comment: But if I use PreparedStatement and do batch update in method saveB, then also is it possible to rollback both TableA and TableB? I am not  using Spring or EJB here.  only Hibernate

Comment: If everything that is updated (or inserted or deleted) within one transaction will be rolled back. Keep in mind, though, that only data in the database will be rolled back. Changes you made to your Java objects will not.

Comment: If I use a single session to update into multiple tables and if the data amount is huge, is there any chance for the session getting overflowed ?

Comment: It might be. The database has to keep track of the data to commit. It it is too much you will get a SQLException. How much too much is depends on the configuration of the database. You might also keep an eye on the number of objects created and kept during the processing. If you run into problems, you'd have to try and make multiple smaller transactions. How huge is your *huge*?